# jquery mobile links not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am getting error on clicking any link in my application.
Here is the error is firebug console

```
uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: data-url='/sap(bD1lbiZjPTIwMA==]/bc/bsp/sap/z_jq_desk/test.html
```

And the link is

```html
<a href="test.html" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-inline="true" data-theme="" data-icon="check">Approve</a>
```

Does anyone have an idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: URL is a unrecognized expression? sap(bD1lbiZjPTIwMA==]/bc/bsp/sap/z_jq_desk/test

Comment: which device is causing the problem? or is it on a desktop runthrough? I'm assuming mobile development here

Comment: yes i am using jquery mobile and testing the application on desktop firefox version 10.

Comment: Try removing the data-theme="" attribute as it's blank

Comment: Can you post a link to your site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the parenthesis in the URL. I am using the latest stable version 1.0.1 of query mobile. The bug is explained in the link below.
I copied over the bug fix to my jQuery mobile library and now ajax navigation is working fine.

Here is the link for the bug and the fix:-
https://github.com/michaelhull/jquery-mobile/commit/0ecd1c71422f014a1ef1335763336251ebf6684f#diff-0

Answer (score 0):

I'd strip everything out but what's required.

```
<a href="test.html" data-role="button">Approve</a>
```

Run that and see what happens.

You might also make sure your link is root relative too.

/path/to/test.html

Even if test.html is in the same directory as your current file, that doesn't mean that's where jQuery Mobile thinks it is.

Comment: what I found out from my search... the root cause seems to be parenthesis in my url. So now I am looking how I can remove the parenthesis in the url..